# is `const_cast`ing away const on a reference worth it to preserve the api

Tags: c++, const-cast, sycl, dpc++

We have the specific case with the GPU programing paradigm sycl as [described in this fix request](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/SYCL-Docs/issues/10) where we want to use read only access from a buffer. Specifically image the use case like:

```
namespace my_lib {

using buffer_type = sycl::buffer<2>;

void process_image(sycl::queue& queue, const buffer_type& input, buffer_type& output);

}
```

This is a sensible interface, the queue which is passed to all operations is mutable, the input is const, the output is not. However, due to the fix request mentioned above, internally this will lead to:

```
void process_image(sycl::queue& queue, const buffer_type& input, buffer_type& output) {
    // ...
    auto input_accessor = input.get_access<sycl::access::read>(cgh);
    // ...
}
```

Which will inevitably fail to compile with:

```
src/gpu_lib/process_image.ipp:112:22: error: no matching member function for call to 'get_access'
                    .get_access<sycl::access::mode::read>(cgh);
                    ~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/opt/intel/oneapi/compiler/2023.0.0/linux/bin-llvm/../include/sycl/buffer.hpp:489:3: note: candidate function template not viable: 'this' argument has type 'const sycl::buffer<float, 2, sycl::detail::aligned_allocator<float>, void>', but method is not marked const
  get_access(
  ^
```

So we come to a decision point, we can either have the API (`buffer_type& input`) as non-const, which is somewhat lying to the user, because it will not be modified. Or, we use `const_cast` to allow this behaviour:

```
  sycl::accessor input_acc =
                const_cast<std::remove_cvref_t<decltype(input)>&>(input)
                    .get_access<sycl::access::mode::read>(cgh);
```

This leads to 2 questons:

1. Is casting away the constness of this reference safe?
2. Which is the better option? Is there a definitive answer on this?

Comment: How about this? Wrap a `private: mutable sycl::buffer` in a class, write a const-correct getter for it, and a `process_image(...) const` method that ignores const-correctness.

Comment: Feels like a library design issue on sycl's part. Kinda the same as C++20 views

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please define safe. It's UB-prone.

The github topic mentions that `implementations may modify the state of the buffer even if it is const`.

I cannot say for the authors, but this seems like a sound reason not to make it const. I dare say, making the function accept the `const buffer_type&` is lying to the user more, because that's not compatible with `buffer_type`'s API.

If `get_access` function should be made const and some `buffer_type`'s members mutable is another story; it is an option to consider if possible.

But for the sake of just using the API, I would opt for making the reference non-const.

Comment: "_No, it's UB (undefined behaviour)._": That depends entirely on the behavior of `get_access` and the `const`ness of the referred-to object.

Comment: i think it's only ub if the orig object was decl const and you try to do a write on the object after casting away const.  in this case it's clear (?) that only a read is being done, so shouldn't be ub.

Comment: Note the github topic: `implementations may modify the state of the buffer even if it is const`. So either way, there's a very good potential for UB

Comment: Did you misunderstand the concept? Just because the parameter is a `const` reference does not mean that the object that it references is `const`. If it isn't, then there is nothing wrong from the language point of view. But even if it is, Sycl seems to imply well-defined behavior as per your citation, because it gives implementations leeway to modify a const object. But that has nothing to do with OP's concern.

Comment: @j6t edited. I might have not been clear enough.

Comment: I read deep into the hipsycl implementation of this. They do appear to modify the element in some way when the buffer accessor is created, even for read only.

Answer (score 0):

Casting away the constness is safe, as long as

- the underlying object is not actually const
- you don't actually modify the underlying object (if it is truly const)

So, in your case I would say (not a definitive answer) you can preserve the function signature and just hack it around with `const_cast` in that one place. Put some comments around why it's needed.

Another notable case where `const_cast` is required (encouraged) is [when you pass a slice of Eigen matrix](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/TopicFunctionTakingEigenTypes.html) to a function. The situation is opposite to yours (here you actually want to modify the object bound to const ref), but maybe will give you some more insight.